# Python vectorize nested for loop with conditionals

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How can I vectorize a nested for loop containing some conditionals? I'm trying to get a list of row/column windows within a very large array. What I have below is quick for a nested loop going through all the rows and columns with a given window size but I'm wondering if there is any way to make this faster.

```
def get_windows(width, height, win_size):
    windows = list()
    
    for i in range(0, width, win_size):
        if i + win_size < width:
            numCols = win_size
        else:
            numCols = width - i
        for j in range(0, height, win_size):
            if j + win_size< height:
                numRows = win_size
            else:
                numRows = height - j
            window = [i, j, numCols, numRows]
            windows.append(window)
    
    return windows

def sliding_window(arr, windows):
    for i in windows:
        win_arr = arr[0:3, i[0]:i[0]+i[2], i[1]:i[1]+i[2]]
        win_arr = np.transpose(win_arr, [1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: `i` and `j` take fixed values determined in the function call. You could calculate the threshold  `i + win_size < width` (and the same for `j` and then populate the list without recalculating it every iteration.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the result? Are you trying to then apply these windows to an array?

Comment: Yes, the intent is to get these windows and apply them to the original ndarray to get the data within those windows. So its a sliding window across 1-4d arrays (very large images)

Comment: I edited to show the remainder of what I'm ultimately accomplishing and trying to speed up

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your edits. Two questions: 1, should `win_arr = np.transpose(arr, [1, 2, 0])` be `win_arr = np.transpose(win_arr, [1, 2, 0])` and 2. doesn't `win_arr` get overwritten on every pass through the loop? Do you mean to be appending `win_arr` to a list?

Comment: Apologies, yes `win_arr = np.transpose(win_arr, [1, 2, 0])` is correct and no `win_arr` does not need to be returned or written to a list. I was accidentally returning it for some reason. `win_arr` is transposed and has additional operations done to it before moving on to the next window so its not needed to be returned.

Comment: I wonder if you want a sliding window, https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Comment: @hpaulj That was one of the first things I tried but couldn't quite get it to work, it kept complaining about the shape/ dimensions I was providing. Definitely something I need to revisit

Comment: @andrewr, the code in your example does not have the same behavior as `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`

Comment: @RoySmart can you elaborate? I'm not too familiar with `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` but I am trying to accomplish a sliding window

Comment: @andrewr, `sliding_window_view` moves the window by one pixel for every window, simlar to this [example](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/arbitrary_padding_no_strides.gif). As I understand your code, and in my answer below, the window moves by `win_size` pixels for every window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use repeated calls to [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to accomplish your goals.

```py
import numpy as np

def sliding_window(arr, win_size):
    for win_arr_x in np.array_split(arr, win_size, axis=-2):
        for win_arr in np.array_split(win_arr_x, win_size, axis=-1):
            win_arr = np.transpose(win_arr, [1, 2, 0])
```