# How to vectorize a nested loop for data collection in Python?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I wanted to make the title 'How to vectorize a non-mathematical script?' instead of what it is because I'm wondering if non-mathematical scripts (involving for loops) can even be vectorized.

I have a script that collects audio data from a CDN, and I'm estimating 50 hours for the completion time. I know about vectorization using NumPy, but I've mostly seen it used for arithmetic and vector operations like dot products, sums and statistical computations.

I don't know where to start when trying to vectorize something more complicated like a data collection script. I thought it would be possible to vectorize it because the vectorization does not depend on the function or process we're dealing with (e.g. summing numbers, looping to collect data).

Here's my script with an outline describing it. It works, but is very slow:

```py
"""
========== OUTLINE ============
For each chapter [there are always 114, constant]
    For each verse in each chapter [depends on chapter]
        For each reciter of that verse [there are always 26, constant]
            Get the audio content from the CDN
            Create a string representing the .mp3 sample with all the information needed
            Store this .mp3 sample in the sub directory of the form 'data/{n_chapter}_{n_verse}'
"""
def create_data_dirs():
    for n_chapter in range(1, 115):
        print(f'In chapter {n_chapter}') 
        for n_verse in range(chapter_range[str(n_chapter)][0], chapter_range[str(n_chapter)][1] + 1):
            print(f'In verse {n_verse} in chapter {n_chapter}') # n_verse should be within chapter's range
            if not os.path.isdir(f'data/{n_chapter}_{n_verse}'):
                os.mkdir(f'data/{n_chapter}_{n_verse}')
                for reciter in bitrates_for_reciters.keys():
                    cdn_link = f'.../{min(bitrates_for_reciters[reciter])}/{reciter}/{n_verse}.mp3'
                    audio = requests.get(cdn_link)
                    # reciter[3:] excludes ar. from the string "ar.reciter_name"
                    with open(f'data/{n_chapter}_{n_verse}/{n_chapter}_{n_verse}_{reciter[3:]}.mp3', 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(audio.content)
```

I was thinking that since I have a third nested for loop, my vectorization would handle a stack of matrices, but I don't know where to go from there, especially because the range of the inner for loop (the number of verses per chapter), depends on the chapter.

I tried to follow the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792040/numpy-vectorization-instead-of-for-loops) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330311/python-vectorize-nested-for-loop-with-conditionals) but I'm finding it hard to generalize these approaches to my case because the problems in these posts are numerical whereas mine is not.

This is all I can attempt:

```py
n_chapters = 114 # [n_rows]
n_verses = ... # [n_cols], depends on chapter
n_reciters = 26 # [n_frames]

# ...?
```

Any ideas on how I could vectorize this process?

Comment: It seems that the bottleneck is downloading (`requests.get()`) files from the CDN. Vectorizing here won't help anything. You should look at `mutliprocessing` and/or `asyncio` libraries to parallelize the downloads.

Comment: So am I correct to understand that vectorization is only used for slow loops involving numerical calculations?

Comment: Yes, vectorization is used for *"crunching numbers"* efficiently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization  Here in your example, you're doing network stuff (+ disk operations for saving files).